# Was Croix behind the football match controversy, or did she merely take advantage of it?

Tags: little-witch-academia

A major plot point in the final third of *Little Witch Academia* is a football match between the country Luna Nova is situated in and an unnamed "rival country", in which the rival country was awarded a goal that shouldn't have been awarded, leading to widespread protests. It's soon revealed that Croix has been covertly helping to escalate the protests and then feeding off the resultant negative emotions, in order to power her Noire Fuel Spirit.

I was expecting it to be revealed that Croix had somehow been responsible for the "goal" being awarded in the first place, but as far as I can tell, the details surrounding the events of the match are never really explained. Considering that those events *literally* fuel the last third of the plot, I find this a little unsatisfying.

**Is there any evidence to suggest that Croix masterminded the controversy from the beginning?** Or did it happen on its own, and she merely took advantage of it?